# Why are entity queries significantly slower than projections in Breeze?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, angularjs, odata, breeze

I have a WebAPI2/OData Breeze server (.NET 4.5, EntityFramework 6) that I'm querying from a Breeze/AngularJS client.  I expected running a full entity query to be slower than running a projection, but I expected it to be somewhat proportional to the amount of data crossing the wire.  But if I run a projection like:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Users')
    .where('firstName', 'startsWith', 'K')
    .select('firstName');

return manager
    .executeQuery(query)
    .then(querySucceeded, _queryFailed);
```

I get 45KB of data, and the request takes 15ms. (Release mode)

And I run a full entity query like:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Users')
    .where('firstName', 'startsWith', 'K');

return manager
    .executeQuery(query)
    .then(querySucceeded, _queryFailed);
```

I get 159KB of data, and the request takes 154ms. (Release mode)

That makes the entity query return about 3x the data, but it takes 10x longer.  The discrepancy is even more apparent if I run in Debug mode.  Then the projection takes 39ms, but the full entity query takes a full 8120ms(!), which makes debugging a bit of a pain.  So in Debug mode the full entity query actually takes over 200x longer than the projection.

Why would a full entity query take disproportionately longer, and in Debug mode in particular? Is this normal, or is this indicative of some issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projection queries can be much faster than 'entity' queries in Breeze because, in general, there is no need to merge the result of a projection into the EntityManager cache, which is a time consuming process if you have a lot of entities. ( Some caveat's here if the projection itself contains entities).

If you do not need this capability or only want it some of the time Breeze has a 'noTracking' method that you can call on the query. (see: the 'noTracking' section on this page: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/querying-depth ). No tracking queries, especially those involving a lot of entities will be MUCH faster.

In terms of Debug vs Release performance, this is presumably purely a 'server side' issue and in my experience is largely a Visual Studio artifact.

Note that if most of your work is just client side javascript can have your server run in a separate solution in 'Release' mode, and just start it up once and leave it running. Iterating during the development of the client side is then much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I don't think that building the entity cache is the source of the issue though, because (I should have been clearer) the metric I'm using is the latency for the request to be processed from the server.  I tried a test with `noTracking()` and saw no difference in server latency.

Comment: noTracking is purely a client side issue. The server query should be pretty fast, so I'm guessing that you got something else going on, but  again Visual Studio Debug can be very slow as opposed to a full release build running outside of Visual Studio. I've seen 20x differences in some cases).

Comment: So leaving Debug issues aside, in Release mode, does 10x longer for entity query (that gets 3x more data) sound within the realm of reasonable expectation?  If so, then I guess there's no issue.

Comment: Are we talking purely server side? Maybe, maybe not, but try adding one additional small property to the projection. Serializing a simple type may be faster than an anon type, which is what you will get with a 2nd property. Also I would check on the raw EF times between the two queries.

Comment: It didn't seem to make a difference having multiple properties in the projection, but checking out EF was a great suggestion... should have done that from the beginning.  Looks like an EntityFramework issue.  If I do a projection, I get a single query.  Otherwise, I get one `sp_executesql` call for my `Users` (returns 300 Users), and then for each of those 300 Users there are 2 more `sp_executesql` calls (grabbing data from the two related tables). So 601 stored procedure calls in all.  I'm not using `expand` at all, so I'm not sure why it's getting related entities from the database.

Comment: I just discovered that if I just call `.ToList()` on my `DbSet<User>`, it doesn't do all of the sp calls (just one SQL statement).  So it seems to be something Breeze is doing rather than EntityFramework

Comment: Have you got LazyLoading turned off? You want to set `           Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` in your DbContext.  Also see discussion here: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider

Comment: That was it!  I screwed up something in my UoW, and was querying against a DbSet taken from a DbContext that EFContextProvider did not provide.  Should have caught that sooner... sorry for the inconvenience.  The latency is now almost exactly proportional to the amount of data, and latency with Debug on is down to a very reasonable 43ms.